# Proving $\pi$ is irrational without arguing by contradiction

Tags: alternative-proof, irrational-numbers, pi

I know few proofs to prove that $\pi$ is irrational, but in all proofs one thing is common: it is done by the method of contradiction.

So, I am looking for a proof without using contradiction. Is there any such proof?

Comment: Irrational means **not** rational, right?

Comment: Sometimes, people who claim they want a proof by contradiction are satisfied with a direct proof from a result whose proof uses contradiction. Is that within the scope of your aims, or do you want a proof that goes all the way down to the axioms without ever using a proof by contradiction?

Comment: The tag [tag:alternative-proof] is little-known but perfectly relevant here.

Comment: A white lie taught to me in Class 6 or 7: "$\pi$ is the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter. It is not necessary that the circumference or the diameter are both rational; they may be irrational- hence $\pi$ is irrational." This was the "proof" given to us, not by the textbooks, but the by the teachers and it is written in the notebooks of thousands of students (at least those who have attended my school).